# How to use \visible when its contents is enclosed by an environment?

Tags: beamer, multline

How to use `\visible` when its contents is enclosed by `multlined` which in turns contains nested `\visible`?

## MWE

The following MWE does not compile because of `multlined`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,beamer,preview,multi={math},border=12pt]{standalone}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\visible<+->{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{math}
        \displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
        \foo{\int_a^b}\foo{f(x)}\foo{\, \mathrm{d}x}
            \foo{&=}\foo{F(b)}\foo{-F(a)}\\
            \foo{&=}\foo{\cos a}\foo{\sin b}\foo{+}\foo{\sin a }\foo{\cos b}\\
            \foo{&=}
                \foo{\begin{multlined}[t]}
                \foo{ax^4}\foo{+bx^3}\\\foo{+cx^2}\foo{+dx}\foo{+e}\\
                \foo{\end{multlined}}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{math}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

The code above was stolen from Marmot's idea.

## Edit

If I removed the `foo`  for both `\begin{multlined}` and `\end{multlined}`, I got blank frames inserted as you can see from the following animation. Some delays represents the blank frames.

```
\documentclass[12pt,beamer,preview,multi={math},border=12pt]{standalone}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\visible<+->{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{math}
        \displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
        \foo{\int_a^b}\foo{f(x)}\foo{\, \mathrm{d}x}
            \foo{&=}\foo{F(b)}\foo{-F(a)}\\
            \foo{&=}\foo{\cos a}\foo{\sin b}\foo{+}\foo{\sin a }\foo{\cos b}\\
            \foo{&=}
                \begin{multlined}[t]
                \foo{ax^4}\foo{+bx^3}\\\foo{+cx^2}\foo{+dx}\foo{+e}\\
                \end{multlined}
    \end{aligned}
        \end{math}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot wrap `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` in separate macros, they must be within the same `\visible`.

Comment: @samcarter: I thought so but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of two problems:

- the `\begin{}` and `\end{}` of an environment must be on the same overlay
- `multiline` processes the code two times. This is a problem if you combine this with your use of `<+->` because twice as many overlays are created than necessary.

I suggest the following workaround:

```
\documentclass[12pt,beamer,preview,multi={math},border=12pt]{standalone}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\visible<+->{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{math}
        \displaystyle
        \begin{aligned}
        \foo{\int_a^b}\foo{f(x)}\foo{\, \mathrm{d}x}
            \foo{=&}\foo{F(b)}\foo{-F(a)}\\
            \foo{=&}\foo{\cos a}\foo{\sin b}\foo{+}\foo{\sin a }\foo{\cos b}\\
            \foo{=& }
            \foo{ ax^4}\foo{+bx^3}\\
            \foo{&+cx^2}\foo{+dx}\foo{+e}\\
        \end{aligned}
        \end{math}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: be careful with a strange spacing before the first term of the polynomial.

Comment: @TheInventorofGod well, insert some space. I'm sure this is easier than adapting `multiline` to play nice with beamer overlays.... Or change the point of alignment from the = sign to the start of the right hand term

Comment: Why did use `=&` instead of `&=`? Are you sure?

Comment: @TheInventorofGod I swapped `&` and `=` because otherwise the `+` would be aligned with the equal signs and I though you wanted it to be aligned with the right hand parts of the equation?

Comment: If you swap then the spacing after `=` becomes uneven (compared to the left one).